# Subtract from one number dynamically

Tags: mysql

I have a base number 30000 and about 5 rows, where every row have different number and i want to subtract them from the base number in query.

I want to achieve the result column:

```
 ID| num  | result
 1 | 1000 | 29000
 2 | 1200 | 27800
 3 | 2100 | 25700
 4 | 4300 | 21400
 5 | 1100 | 20300
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, num, (30000 - @sum:=@sum+num) AS Result
FROM mytable, (SELECT @sum:= 0) AS A
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6265a/1)

Comment: Thats just perfect! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @num := 0;
SELECT 
  id,
  num,
  IF(@num = 0,@num := (30000 - num) , @num := (@num - num)) AS `Result`
FROM
  `mytable`
```

### Demo

Comment: I believe he means he wants to end up with the result column, in which case: (30000 - num) AS Result

Comment: with this logic you'll get every row result like 30000-1000,30000-1200,30000-2100 and so on, but i need to subtract from every row subtraction result. Like 30000-1000,29000-1200,27800-2100 ...

Comment: It does the job, but it's not one query. I got already answer. Thanks for helping.